# Using SoundManager2 along side the Soundcloud HTML5 widget

Tags: soundcloud

I am trying to find out how to use the HTML5 widget and control the panning of the audio.  Is this possible using the Widget?  Or do I need to use the oembed code?

Answer (score 0):

I did not see any panning capabilities with the widget but you can look into the pan feature of soundmanager2 which is used when streaming

streaming info:
http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#javascript

panning info:
http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/